# Can't get max value of a field in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a web app with DRF. I am trying to pass the customer id and display the maximum transaction he has done.

This is my views.py

```
class max_val(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = json.loads(request.body).get('cid')
        queryset = model_name.objects.filter(customer_id=cid).aggregate(Max('transaction'))
        serialize = serializer_name(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I run this I get -

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "customer_id": null,
        "transaction": null
    }
]
```

This is my serialiser -

```
class serialser_name(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        fields = ('customer_id', 'transaction')
```

It is not returning the maximum value. How can I do that ?

Comment: can you share your serializer?

Comment: I added the serialiser

Comment: What kind of value is Transaction? What would the Max look like?

Comment: Transaction is a Numeric value. It should like 1239878.98568

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aggregate not returning object, its just returning dictionary of field_name__max and it's value .try this:

```
class max_val(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = json.loads(request.body).get('cid')
        max_transaction = model_name.objects.filter(customer_id=cid).aggregate(Max('transaction'))
        return Response(max_transaction, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

you can find more information about aggregate [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) .